# How can I dump the view hierarchy from within an Apportable app?

Tags: apportable

Using the Apple private API, `[view recursiveDescription]` returns `nil` on Apportable, how can I dump the view hierarchy? Is it possible, short of building it by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gdb : `print [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] dumpGeometry:0]` will output the hierarchy to logcat.

Also to use Android's hierarchyviewer:

- Build with VIEW_SERVER=yes (or use 'google' labeled Nexus 7)
- Start hierarchyviewer (.apportable/toolchain/macosx/android-sdk/tools/hierarchyviewer)